# How to get Kubernetes Version as integer from API

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, google-kubernetes-engine, semantic-versioning, openshift-3

I am trying to get the current Kubernetes version via the API, because depending on the version some things are not supported (e.g. readyz endpoint is not available before 1.16, so I want to check healthz endpoint instead).

I found the following endpoint: `/version`

Example result:

```
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "11+",
  "gitVersion": "v1.11.0+d4cacc0",
  "gitCommit": "d4cacc0",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2021-05-12T14:13:55Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.10.8",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
}
```

Is this the correct approach to get the version via API? I thaught Kubernetes uses semantic versioning, why is the "+" in the minor String? Is this configurable?
Where can I find a specification of this API/fields?

Ideally this should work for standalone and managed Kubernetes flavors (Openshift, GKE...).

Comment: `GitVersion`/`gitVersion` is the semantic version field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GitVersion`/`gitVersion` is the semantic versioning field.

This is the version of the `kube-api-server` component specifically.

The parsing is done by [regex](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/57f2a0733447cfd41294477d833cce6580faaca3/pkg/util/version/version.go#L35-L40) in The [k8s.io/apimachinery](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery) package:

```
^\s*v?([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)*)(.*)*$`
```

The `/version` endpoint is part of the documented API spec (`operationId: "getCode"`) so should be pretty stable. It's what `kubectl version` uses so I doubt it will change easily.

Comment: for my better understanding , can you please give an example how can we use above regex with endpoint version as a url ?

Comment: The regex is Go from kubectl. The request is made via [kuberenetes discovery client](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/cmd/version/version.go#L123-L128) in the [`ServerVersion`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/da281643cfad72bc8c4565b197ec23b557e30446/discovery/discovery_client.go#L408-L420) function. Parsing and testing is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/81deb1a362e3437bf9242e15451a4856dad27330/pkg/cmd/version/skew_warning.go#L34)

Comment: The OpenAPI operation is `getCode` which is what most generated API clients will expose to you  @confusedgenius